# How long can coconut liquid/cream last (open) in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, coconut

I'm usually left with an unfinished can of coconut cream or liquid when cooking, and I store them in a closed plastic box in the fridge.

**How long can they last?**
It says 3 (for the cream) and 4 (for the liquid), but I already checked it after a week and a half and it smelled and tasted just fine.

Both of the items have shelf life of around 2 years, and doesn't need to be in the fridge before opening, if this information might matter.

**Are there any visual differences when it's no good anymore?**

**Is it possible to save them in the freezer after opening?**

---

#### Extra details:

**Coconut liquid:**

- The coconut liquid ingredients as written on the box are: coconut extract (60%), water.
- The brand is **AROY-D**
- [Looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqvMe.png)

**Coconut cream:**

- 17-19% fat

---

**Edit:** I checked out [this question about coconut milk](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21023/how-long-can-coconut-milk-last-in-the-fridge), but it's not the same - I'm asking about the two other types - liquid and cream (it might be that the answer is similar, but the question is different).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can coconut milk last in the fridge?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21023/how-long-can-coconut-milk-last-in-the-fridge)

Comment: @Luciano Thanks, but it's not the same (the linked question is about coconut milk,  and mine is about liquid and cream, which are different - although the answer might be similar).

Comment: I don't think the advice in the referenced question would be different from your question.  Smell and taste are not reliable indicators of safety.  Once you open a shelf stable item, you create the opportunity for the introduction of pathogens. Freezing (as in the linked question) is an option.

Comment: @moscafj Basically you're correct, but I didn't knew if there are changes I'm not aware of, since it has different components and different fat/water level that I thought can affect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coconut cream, being generally oily, will give out rancidity in taste and smell once it rots. When extracted fresh as done in asia, coconut cream typically expires in a matter of hours. Since yours is canned, it's likely to have been reconstituted from coconut powder, ridding it from the spoiling enzymes in fresh coconut.

As long as you open your cans cold and keep its leftovers cold thereafter, it's easy to beat the printed expiry. The thing with coconut cream and liquid, it rots so suddenly, as soon as you turn your back. So its manufacturers are wary of users who aren't familiar with how sudden these things rot, which is why asians press and cook them within the same few hours.